# Normalize slices of a ndarray

Tags: python, numpy, multidimensional-array

I have a 3 columns array. The first column of the array have values between 1 and 10. I need to extract all lines where the first column is 1 and normalize the third column of this slice of array. Then repeat the same thing for all rows for which the first column is equal to 2 etc.

If I run this code, it leaves the array unchanged:

```
for u in np.unique(x[:,0]):
    mask= x[:, 0] == u
    x[mask][:,2]=x[mask][:,2]/np.sum((x[mask][:,2]))
```

If I run this other slice of code, I see that r (I placed a print r in the loop) actually work exactly as I want. The only point is that the original array x unchanged.

```
for u in np.unique(x[:,0]):
    r = x[x[:, 0] == u]
    r[:,2]=r[:,2]/np.sum((x[x[:,0]==u][:,2]))
```

Why is that? What am I doing wrong???

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's an alternative vectorized approach with performance in mind to solve your problem using [`np.unique`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.10.4/reference/generated/numpy.unique.html) and [`np.bincount`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.bincount.html) -

```
tags = np.unique(x[:,0], return_inverse=1)[1]
x[:,2] /= np.bincount(tags, x[:,2])[tags]
```

To further boost the performance, one can avoid the use of `np.unique` and directly compute the equivalent of `np.bincount(tags, xc[:,2])`, while making use of the fact that the numbers in the first column are between `1` and `10`, with this -

```
np.bincount(xc[:,0].astype(int), xc[:,2], minlength=11)[1:]
```

To replace `tags`, we could use the first column, like so -

```
tags = xc[:,0].astype(int)-1
```

Answer (score 1):

Don't index twice. Apparently then a copy of the source array is created.
Use `x[mask,2]` instead of `x[mask][:,2]`:

```
for u in np.unique(x[:,0]):
    mask= x[:, 0] == u
    x[mask,2]=x[mask,2]/np.sum((x[mask,2]))
```